# How Can I Get gdb-peda to Show Every 4 bytes of the Stack in 64bit mode?

Tags: python, debugging, gdb, disassembly

I've been using gdb-peda to learn debugging (not for exploits), and on my 64 bit Mac Pro running OS X 10.10 the stack trace shows every 8 bytes, like so:

```
0000| 0x7fff5fbff8b0 --> 0x0
0008| 0x7fff5fbff8b8 --> 0x0
0016| 0x7fff5fbff8c0 --> 0x7fff5fbff8e8 --> 0x0
0024| 0x7fff5fbff8c8 --> 0x40e9999a5fc01036
0032| 0x7fff5fbff8d0 --> 0x7fff5fbff8e8 --> 0x0
0040| 0x7fff5fbff8d8 --> 0x7fff8ced25c9 (<start+1>: mov    edi,eax)
0048| 0x7fff5fbff8e0 --> 0x7fff8ced25c9 (<start+1>: mov    edi,eax)
0056| 0x7fff5fbff8e8 --> 0x0
```

I have seen it print out 4 bytes per line in a few pics on different sites, but the register names all begin with 'e' in those pics, so I assume they're running in 32 bit mode or are on 32 bit machines.

I don't know Python, but I searched through the peda code for all references to 'stack' or the numbers 4 and 8 or 32/64 bit modes, and couldn't find anything which looked likely or had any effect when I changed it. Nor could I find any detailed instructions anywhere online for setting up or modifying peda. I suppose they assume you're a serious hacker and should be able to work it out for yourself.

As it is, I have to view the 'in-between' memory manually, like so:

```
gdb-peda$ x/xw 0x7fff5fbff8a4 // 4 bytes in from rbp
0x7fff5fbff8a4: 0x00007fff    // showing data which wasn't visible in
                              // the stack backtrace
```

(There's nothing relevant in this 4 byte offset from 0x7fff5fbff8a0 now, but sometimes there is.)

How can I get peda to show every four bytes of the stack? Am I missing something obvious or being very obtuse here?

I imagine the idea behind it is that in 64 bit mode you'd expect to be seeing 8 byte (64 bit) chunks of data, so reading every 4 bytes would mean the reads would overlap (interleave?), and reading every 8 bytes would seem to make more sense. But the data doesn't seem to necessarily be in 64 bit/8 byte chunks. I suppose it depends on frame variable size etc., so some data chunks still do start at 4 byte, rather than 8 byte, intervals.

I'm not sure if I'm making myself very clear here. I'm very much a beginner in this area, so please feel free to correct any howling errors I may have made!